# Give border to child divs on click and retain it till next div is clicked, using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, pseudo-class

I have a week calendar made up of multiple divs with `display:flex` property of css in which I am using script to display date and day name of current day and previous 6 days.

I need to highlight the internal divs upon hover/focus, which has been done using `:hover` pseudoclass , however when the user hovers the size of the divs changes.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/w3wguL10/2/) and code snippet.

```
.insider:hover, .insider:visited
{
 border:2px solid white;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 background-color:#595159;
}
```

Also I want the same to happen ,without the size changing glitch, when user clicks on the divs and the css on click should retain till the other div is clicked. Can this second task be achieved without using jquery/javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to remove the *size-changing glitch*, you could just use this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Because on hover you apply a 2px border the boxes will adjust to it as the default `box-sizing` is a `content-box`.

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vosr76Lv/).

To solve this:
*When user clicks on the divs and the css on click should retain till the other div is clicked*

1. It is better to use javascript / jquery.
2. There is no option with CSS directly, but you adopt the following trick by modifying the markup:

```js
var dates = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"];

var dates1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"];

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var today = new Date();
var todaysdate = today.getDate();
var todaysday = today.getDay();
//alert(today.getMonth());
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
  var data = todaysday - i + 1;
  if (data < 0) {
    data = data + 7
  }
  $("#day" + i).append("<span class='daystyle'><font face='Verdana'>" + dayNames[data] + "</font></span><br/><p class='daystyle'>" + (today.getDate() - (i - 1)) + "</p>");

}
var data1 = today.getMonth();

$(".currentmonth").append("<p><font face='Comic sans MS' size='4'>" + monthNames[data1] + "</font></p>");
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainContainer {
  width: 700px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-family: "My Custom Font", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
.insider,
.currentmonth {
  width: 90px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.insider:hover,
.insider:visited {
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #595159;
}
.currentmonth {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
.daystyle {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #595159;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="currentmonth" id="monthname"></div>
  <input type="radio" id="day7-in" name="dummy" />
  <label class="insider" id="day7" for="day7-in"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="day6-in" name="dummy" />
  <label class="insider" id="day6" for="day6-in"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="day5-in" name="dummy" />
  <label class="insider" id="day5" for="day5-in"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="day4-in" name="dummy" />
  <label class="insider" id="day4" for="day4-in"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="day3-in" name="dummy" />
  <label class="insider" id="day3" for="day3-in"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="day2-in" name="dummy" />
  <label class="insider" id="day2" for="day2-in"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="day1-in" name="dummy" />
  <label class="insider" id="day1" for="day1-in"></label>
</div>
```

Here you are using some hidden `radio buttons` along with their corresponding `labels` and these styles:

```
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #595159;
}
```

This will make it work like 'clicks'!

Comment: Can you care to explain why did you edit the question?? I don't see any difference in it even after your edit.

Comment: @Reddy wrapped the fiddle link into `[label][1]` and linked it with `[1]:https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/w3wguL10/2/` for better viewing... check my revision...

Comment: @rawatdeepesh please let me know your thoughts on the answer... Thanks!

Comment: My apologies for the late reply . Thanks kukkuz it did work. I made some changes to the script. its a bit long, may be it could be written in a shorter way.Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/w3wguL10/8/

Comment: cool, nice to know it helped you :)... could you please upvote the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I did, Thanks again. Is there a way to optimise the script in the same code ?
[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3wguL10/8/)